# Regular expression to match a range of numbers decimals (1 - 155)

Tags: regex, numbers

Looking to match all sums from `£1` to `£155` with an optional set of pence digits after a full stop, so `£59.65` matches, and `£0.47` and `£155.56` won't match.

Here is what I have so far:

```
£\d{1,3}([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-5][0-5])(?:[,.])?\d{1,2}
```

**Natural Numbers and Decimals between 1 - 155**

Comment: Is regex your only available tool?

Comment: Is a leading zero allowed for numbers greater than or equal to one?

Comment: Removing the `£` and checking the numerical value would probably be the easiest...depending on where you are using this. `if(x >= 1 and x <= 155) { //valid`

Comment: Yes sadly. No leading zeros ideally. How would I do that? Fairly new to regex.

Comment: Regex for values from 1 to 155:`( ( [1-9] | (1?[0-4]\d) | ([5-9]\d) )(\.\d\d) ) | 155`

Comment: @Meninx-メネンックス `(1?[0-4]\d)` would allow `00`. Also spacing issues, `(\.\d\d)`

Comment: @chris85 yep miss it `( ( [1-9] | (1?[1-4]\d) | (10\d) | ([5-9]\d) )(\.\d\d) ) | 155` I intentionally kept the spaces for clarity ;). OP needs of course to remove them to make it work.

Comment: @Meninx-メネンックス You are only allowing for decimals  on 50-99.

Comment: Need to remove first `(` sorry `([1-9]|(1?[1-4]\d)|(10\d)|([5-9]\d))(\.\d\d)?|155(\.00)?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about:

```
£((\d|[1-9]\d|1[0-4]\d|15[0-4])(\.\d{2})?|155(\.00)?)
```

The regex works as follows: it always starts with the leading pound sign (`£`). Next it considers two cases: the one where the value is less than `155` and the one where it is `155`. The case of `155` is simple: `155(\.00)?`: `155` optionally followed by a dot and two zeros.

The case of less than `155` is more complex: we branch into several cases:

- the one with one digit `\d` (zero to nine);
- the one with two digits, but no leading zeros: `[1-9]\d`;
- the one with three digits: but since the result should be less than `155` we again have to branch:

  - the ones less than `150`: these start with a `1` followed by a number between `0` and `4` (inclusive) followed by any digit `\d`, so `1[0-4]\d`;
  - the ones greater than or equal to `150`, but less than `155`, these all start with `15` and are followed by something in the range of `0` to `4` (inclusive), so `15[0-4]`.

All these are followed optionally by a dot and two digits (`\.\d{2}`).

This regex reject numbers with leading zeros (like `09.12`) except of course if there is one digit: `0.85` is allowed.

I here assumed there are always two digits after the decimal dot(so `0.1` and `14.135` are not allowed), in case an arbitrary amount is allowed, simply replace `\.\d{2}` with `\.\d+` (in case at least one digit is required), or `\.\d*` if even no digits are allowed.

Comment: And this is downvoted because... Although I agree regexes are not the way to check integer bounds, it can be done as is demonstrated here.

Comment: Your pattern works well, except it doesn't check cases when there is only one digit after the dot/comma (1.1) or more than two digits (155.001).

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: well based on the comment, I think there are exactly two digits allowed (I don't know prices where they show one or three digits, except for gas stations). I agree I don't take these into account, but the pattern can easily be expanded.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: I've added a little note that one can easily extend the regex pattern.

Comment: I found this: `£([1-9]{1,2}(\.[0-9]{2})?|1[0-5][0-4](\.[0-9]{2})?|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-4]?[0-9]?|155(?!\.))\b` to work.

Comment: @Jimmy: this does not match `£155.00`.

Answer (score 2):

If lookaheads are supported with your regex flavour, you can try this:

```
£(?:1(?:[0-4](?:[0-9]?(?:[.,][0-9]{1,2})?)?|5(?:[0-4](?:[.,][0-9]{1,2})?|5(?:[.,]00?)?)|[6-9]?(?:[.,][0-9]{1,2})?)?|[2-9][0-9]?(?:[.,][0-9]{1,2})?)(?![.,]?[0-9])
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/rgaVtp/1)

Comment: This works, but doesn't account for the optional "." and two possible pence digits

Comment: @WilliamRose: press F5 to update your page.

Comment: What is the reason of this downvote?

Comment: Don't you think it is **too long** !!.

Comment: @Meninx-メネンックス: It's longer that your version in comment, but it's more efficient since each branch are sorted by probability. This way you avoid useless tests.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte for treating **comma** case.

Comment: @Meninx-メネンックス: I just updated my answer *(missing some cases)*. Check it now